# How to change color of QOpenGLWidget when a QPushButton is pressed

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qobject

I would like control my `QOpenGLWidget` with buttons. Here is what've tried so far, but it is not working.

white coloring function in class `GLWidget` promoted to my widget.

```
void GLWidget::nabialo(){
    glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
    update();
}
```

Slot function (called when the `QPushButton` is pressed):

```
void MainWindow::Koloruj()
{
    ui->WidgetNadawanie->nabialo(); //WidgetNadawanie is my widget.
}
```

And this is my call to `connect`:

```
QObject::connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(Koloruj()));
```

I want to change the color of `QOpenGLWidget` by pressing `QPushButton`. If my code is badly wrong please give my some advice or example.

Comment: *doesn't work* is not a good problem description, what exactly happens? what do you expect instead? try putting some `qDebug` messages to see where exactly your code is executing in order to narrow the problem down.

Comment: In my opinion code is executing in proper way, but the color of QOpenGLWidget doesn't change. I mean it is the same as in `initializeGL()` function. Is the `glFlush` and  `update` used correctly?

Comment: You're calling OpenGL functions but not checking for any error conditions.  Is there an active OpenGL context when `GLWidget::nabialo` is called?  I'm guessing not based on the code you've shown.